# Rotate an object on its local axis using global rotation?

Tags: math, 3d, rotation

I want an object that rotates on a relative axis (the axis rotates with it) to rotate as if it's axis hadn't moved.

In a game (not my own) I have an object that stays in view of the player at all times (it follows the camera). I also want said object to keep the same rotation relative to the camera so it always looks like the same orientation to the player. It is simple to make it hold an orientation with modified X or Z values relative to the camera yaw, but once I rotate the object on the Y axis, the X axis has moved to the camera pitch makes the object rotate incorrectly (the roll would be affected too).

I am pretty sure it will require either a matrix or a combination of sin/cos, but I have had no luck in finding an answer.

Note: Rotation is in pitch, yaw, and roll using radians on the x, y, and z-axis respectively.

Comment: Do you have the camera model transform matrix and can you set the object's model transform matrix? If not, what information do you have and what can you set?

Comment: I don't have any matrices, no. I can get and set the model rotation with pitch, yaw, and roll. I can get the camera look vector, pitch, and yaw, and set them all as well (the camera has no roll).